# How is row elimination getting rid of this entry?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a really elementary question, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something conceptual. In Strang's book *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, on p. 321, he introduces tests for positive definiteness and semidefiniteness. As an example he shows that the matrix $$ \left [ \begin {matrix}  2 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2\end {matrix} \right ]$$

is positive semi-definite. One criterion he uses is that no pivots are negative. To demonstrate this, he writes:

> $$A = \left [ \begin {matrix}  2 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2\end {matrix} \right ] \rightarrow \left [ \begin {matrix}  2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac32 & -\frac32 \\ 0 & -\frac32 &  \frac32 \end {matrix} \right ] \rightarrow \left [ \begin {matrix}  2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac32 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mathbf{0}\end {matrix} \right ] \text { (missing pivot).}$$

How has he gotten from step 2 to step 3? Row elimination would not get rid of the $-\frac32$ in slot $2,3$ would it? I just want to make sure I correctly understand row elimination and how to uncover the pivots.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. The second matrix and the third matrix are not compatible (that is, the variable values that would solve the second matrix would not solve the third). Therefore, he has changed the system, contrary to the inherent nature of elementary row operations.

Comment: Perhaps he's not saying they are row equivalent, but something else? Given $$\left [ \begin {matrix}  2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac32 & -\frac32 \\ 0 & -\frac32 &  \frac32 \end {matrix} \right ],$$ how does one find the pivots?

Comment: In the matrix you just posted, the (2,2) entry is the pivot, because it's the next non-zero number you'd use to do the next calculation. In this case, the next ERO would zero out the entire third row. At that point, you would have no pivot, because the algorithm is finished.

Comment: Since we're not allowed to do row exchanges when we test the pivots for positivity, what happens if we run out of pivots in the middle of the process? How can we figure out if all the pivots are $\geq 0$, for example, if we end up with a zero on the second step?

Comment: If you're talking about something like $$\begin{bmatrix}2 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &1 \\ 0 &3 &-1\end{bmatrix},$$ then you'd have to go to the next row.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "go to the next row"? How do we determine what the pivots are?

Comment: Ok, so in the matrix I just gave you, you'd have started off looking at the (1,1) position for ERO's. You'd use ERO's to get zeros in the (2,1) and (3,1) positions. The matrix I posted is what you would have next. Now normally, the pivot position would be the (2,2) position. But there's a zero there, which is not allowed. Since you're not allowed to exchange rows (which is one of the ERO's), you would then simply need to switch your attention to the next row but the same column, which would be the (3,2) position. Does that make sense?

Comment: No idea how Strang treats it, but "positive (semi-)definite" is a thing concerning bilinear/hermitian forms, and thus the transformation of the matrices is $P^T A P$ (or $P^\ast A P$) and not $P^{-1}AP$, for each row operation, you also apply the corresponding column operation. So in the last step, you have "add second row to third, then add second column to third" (or do the column operation first, no difference).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Perhaps we're talking past each other. What is the objective of the algorithm you're doing? I'm trying to figure out if a particular symmetric matrix is positive (semi-) definite by examining the pivots, since a necessary and sufficient condition for positive (semi-) definiteness.

Comment: @DanielFischer Are you aware of a test for positive (semi-) definiteness involving the "pivots"? Perhaps the point is that we need not go to the trouble of finding the eigenvectors; any congruence relation producing $P^T A P = D$ will suffice if we just check if the diagonal of $D$ is composed of positive (non-negative) entries. But what if we end up with something like $$\left [ \begin {matrix}  2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac32 \\ 0 & \frac32 & 0 \end {matrix} \right ]?$$ Can we deduce anything there? Or are we just consigned to do the work of finding the right $P^T A P$ so it is truly diagonal?

Comment: I'm not even sure what a "pivot" is (we didn't use that terminology when I learned linear algebra), though I can make a guess. In the example you give, it's clear that you have an indefinite matrix because the bottom-right $2\times 2$ minor has negative determinant/you see the eigenvalue $-3/2$. If you want a "works always without thinking" rule, add the third row (and column) to the second to get $$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&3&\frac32\\0&\frac32&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and then go on from there to reach $$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&-\frac34\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that Strang was suggesting a congruency transformation rather than row equivalence. For $A$ symmetric, $A = L D L^T$ for $D$ diagonal, and we can look at the entries of $D$ to determine positive (semi-) definiteness.

Comment: Provided of course that LDL^T is diagonal, which it need not be.

Answer (score 1):

Strang's book does have many typos and even has some outright errors, so one shouldn't be too hard on oneself if something doesn't quite make sense.  In fact I find Strang's book to be very confusing and difficult to understand even though I know a lot of linear algebra.  In my opinion the best way to study out of Strang is to have a clearer textbook handy to help decipher what he is saying.

That said, he gets the third matrix from the second by adding row 2 to row three to get all the zeros on the bottom row; then adding column 2 to column 3 to get all zeros in the 3rd column.  (This last step is unnecessary, but whatever).

That leaves you with 2 positive pivots and one zero pivot, which fits the pivot based definition of positive semi-definite.  I'm not a great fan of pivots, as I find them a little confusing.  I would translate the 3rd matrix as meaning that  the original matrix has one zero and two positive eigenvalues. One way of defining positive semi-definite is that all the eigenvalues are non-negative, at least one is zero, and at least one is > 0.  This is equivalent to any other definition of positive semi-definite, and I think it is the easiest of all of them to understand.